# Running perl script within Java

Tags: java, perl, runtime

I wanted to run this `zipTransfer.pl` perl program from within a function in Java

```
private void runZipTransfer() throws IOException {


Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] {"C:\\Perl64\\bin", "C:\\Lazy\\zipTransfer.pl"});


}
```

When running my Java program, however, nothing happens! Where's the issue here?

Answer (score 1):

You need to execute the perl interpreter:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] {"C:\\Perl64\\bin\\perl.exe", "C:\\Lazy\\zipTransfer.pl"});
```

Comment: Not sure what's really going on here..that's the location of my perl exe

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] {"perl", "C:\\Lazy\\zipTransfer.pl"});
```